# InkCanvas: How to erase by Stroke on right mouse click

Tags: erase, stroke, inkcanvas, right-mouse-button

I have an InkCanvas that works in the InkCanvasEditingMode.Ink. But I want to erase the entire stroke when the user presses the right button. Help me with an advise, please?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure which stroke you are willing to erase, but InkCanvas has a "Stokes" property that contains all strokes of the canvas. 
For example, to remove all strokes from canvas:

```
inkCanvas.Strokes.Clear()
```

Now all you have to do is to puck the relevant one.

Comment: This will clear all drown.